# Oversized parentheses around tabular

Tags: tables, delimiters, linguistics

I'm having the following problem. I'm using a tabular environment to create a phrase structure rule (linguistics stuff, don't care about it) and I need parentheses for those parts in the rule which are optional. This is a demo code of what I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\symb}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\normalsize{#1}\\
\footnotesize{#2}
\end{tabular}}
% Optional rule support
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
% Macros
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\blank}{\ensuremath{\quad}}

\begin{document}
    \symb{IP}{}\blank
    \symb{\ra}{}\blank
    \opt{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            \normalsize{TopicP}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = \da}}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = (\ua TopicPath)}}
        \end{tabular}
    }\blank
    \opt{\symb{IP}{\ua = \da}}
\end{document}
```

I know the code isn't the most elegant thing you'll ever see. It's because I've had to modify a somewhat well-known macro used for LFG phrase structure rules... which sadly doesn't support more than one annotation. Thus, I'm using the tabular in order to have more than one annotation under the phrasal category (NP, IP, whatever).

Thanks!

Comment: As reference to your use of old font macros, please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the position specifier `[t]` in `\begin{tabular}{c}` everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\symb}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\normalsize{#1}\\
\footnotesize{#2}
\end{tabular}}
% Optional rule support
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
% Macros
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\blank}{\ensuremath{\quad}}

\begin{document}
    \symb{IP}{}\blank
    \symb{\ra}{}\blank
    \opt{
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \normalsize{TopicP}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = \da}}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = (\ua TopicPath)}}
        \end{tabular}
    }\blank
    \opt{\symb{IP}{\ua = \da}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The specifier `[t]` will align the tabular at the top, `[c]` at the center and `[b]` at the bottom as noted by cyberSingularity.

Comment: Hm... but that doesn't make the tabular to be aligned to the top of the "IP ->"

Comment: And similarly in the definition of `\symb` for the "IP". It might be worth explaining why the issue is caused and what `[t]` and `[c]` (default) do.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the optional `[t]` positioning argument from the `tabular`s; to keep the alignment of `IP ->` with the first line of the you can use another three row `tabular`, having `\symb{IP}{}\blank\symb{\ra}{}\blank` in the first row and two other empty rows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\symb}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\normalsize #1\\
\footnotesize #2
\end{tabular}}
% Optional rule support
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
% Macros
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\blank}{\quad}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \symb{IP}{}\blank
    \symb{\ra}{}\blank \\ \\
    \end{tabular}%
    \opt{
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \normalsize{TopicP} \\
            \footnotesize \scshape (\ua topic) = \da\\
            \footnotesize \scshape (\ua topic) = (\ua TopicPath)
        \end{tabular}
    }\blank
    \opt{\symb{IP}{\ua = \da}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also changed the obsolete `\sc` to `\scshape` and suppressed some superfluous braces (`\fontnotesize`, `\normalsize` and `\schape` don't take arguments). Also, as **egreg** mentions in his comment, since `\quad` is not a math mode command, `\newcommand{\blank}{\quad}` is a more correct definition.

Comment: Also `\quad` is not a math mode command, so `\newcommand{\blank}{\quad}` is "more correct"; `\footnotesize` and `\normalsize` don't take arguments.

Comment: @egreg you're right about `\blank`; (about the font declarations too, but I had already made the changes and the comment).

Comment: @egreg Ah, now I see that I had missed some font declarations still with braces; I've fixed them too now. Thnaks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want top aligned tables with delimiters you can use `delarray`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{delarray}

\newcommand{\symbx}[4]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]#1{c}#2
\normalsize{#3}\\
\footnotesize{#4}
\end{tabular}}
\newcommand\symb{\symbx{}{}}
\newcommand\bsymb{\symbx()}
% Optional rule support
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
% Macros
\newcommand{\ra}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ua}{\ensuremath{\uparrow}}
\newcommand{\da}{\ensuremath{\downarrow}}
\newcommand{\blank}{\ensuremath{\quad}}

\begin{document}
    \symb{IP}{}\blank
    \symb{\ra}{}\blank
        \begin{tabular}[t]({c})
            \normalsize{TopicP}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = \da}}\\
            \footnotesize{{\sc (\ua topic) = (\ua TopicPath)}}
        \end{tabular}
    \blank
    \bsymb{IP}{\ua = \da}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note I only addressed the question of alignment, @egreg's comments re font command usage all apply:-)